# Download very large files with HTTP

Tags: data-recovery, download, tcp, gzip

I'm downloading the [PlaceNet](http://places.csail.mit.edu/user/download.php) compressed database of place images (~132GiB). Unluckily the downloaded file is corrupted. I have tried several times, each time the extraction is stopped at different positions (approx. offsets could be 10GiB, 30GiB, etc.) [PlaceNet](http://places.csail.mit.edu/user/download.php) doesn't provide splitted versions for downloading. Well, the problem should be some bytes in the downloaded file, What can I do to avoid re-downloading the whole file again?

My ideas are:

1. Is there TCP extension for an enhanced datagram checksum? And how to use it?
2. Can I see the offset (approx.) to the first error byte when *gunzip*ping?
3. I'm using [axel](https://github.com/eribertomota/axel) to download. When the download completes, is it possible to re-download some parts of the file again? I.e., create the `XXX.st` file for axel, mark some range as undownloaded, and run axel again.

Comment: I see the download page is now private. If that's because their server were overloaded, they should provide torrents...

Answer (score 1):

You can try a different approach, i.e. using a FUSE wrapper to "mount" a remote file via HTTP and the invoke standard tools on it. The tools will try to read specific bytes and those attempts will be translated to HTTP byte-range GET requests.

This has been discussed on StackOverflow, in [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15321699/1101509) by [Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/321772/adam) which uses [HTTPFS](http://httpfs.sourceforge.net/):

> **Mount a remote zip file and extract one file from it:**
>
> ```
> mkdir mount_pt
> sudo ./httpfs http://server.com/zipfile.zip mount_pt
> sudo ls mount_pt zipfile.zip
> sudo unzip -p mount_pt/zipfile.zip the_file_I_want.txt > the_file_I_want.txt
> sudo umount mount_pt
> ```

In your case, if the file is not a ZIP but e.g. a `tar.gz` file (I can't check because the link you provided requires registration) then you could adapt the steps:

```
mkdir mount_pt
sudo ./httpfs http://example.com/file.tar.gz mount_pt
sudo tar xzvf mount_pt/file.tar.gz
```

Or even call `file-roller` or another GUI tool on the archive.

Comment: Does that even handle multithreading/simultaneous connections? http://httpfs.sourceforge.net/techinfo.htm says "It also doesn't exploit keep alive connections".

Comment: I have not explored how it is implemented.